# Cannot display image from parent to child

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have code like this in `index.js` in is parents file

```
import KOD1 from '../../assets/KOD/milktea.png'
import KOD2 from '../../assets/KOD/juice.png'
import KOD3 from '../../assets/KOD/juice1.png'
import KOD4 from '../../assets/KOD/milktea1.png'

 class Home extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
        <section className="kind-of-drink">
            <h4 className="main-title"> Kind of drinks we sell</h4>
            <Row className="kod-content">
              <Col className="kod-image">
                <ImageItem src={KOD1}/>
              </Col>

              <Col className="kod-image">
                <ImageItem src={KOD2}/>
              </Col>

              <Col className="kod-image">
                <ImageItem src={KOD3}/>
              </Col>

              <Col className="kod-image">
                <ImageItem src={KOD4}/>
              </Col>
            </Row>
         </section>
 );
 }
}
```

And this is child file `index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import {Image} from 'react-bootstrap';
import '../Image/index.css';

const ImageItem = ({image}) => {
  return(
    <Image className="prod-kind-image" src={image}/> 
  );
}

export default ImageItem;
```

I don't understand why when I import the image from parents to the child it goes wrong where it doesn't display the image
[image]

I don't know where I'm wrong, can you take a bit time to support me about this please, Thank you so much

Comment: import React from 'react';
import {Image} from 'react-bootstrap';
import '../Image/index.css';

const ImageItem = ({src}) => {
  return(
    <Image className="prod-kind-image" src={src}/> 
  );
}

export default ImageItem;

Comment: @SantoshSagar Thank so much, it's worked

Comment: Easy on the ALL CAPS, especially in titles. It's considered yelling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing image to ImageItem in `src` props. You need to change the implementation of ImageItem.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Image} from 'react-bootstrap';
import '../Image/index.css';

const ImageItem = ({src}) => {
  return(
    <Image className="prod-kind-image" src={src}/> 
  );
}

export default ImageItem;
```